# WPF Text foreground color of whole column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an application which user can switch to one of 4 different color themes. For that color themes I'm using 4 different xaml resource dictionaries.
Also application is using datagrids bound to datatables loaded from DB. These datagrids always have different coloured first column than the other columns.

Problem occures when user switches the theme. Everything changes correctly (according to settings in res. dictionry) except text in the first column.

Here is my definition of brush in res. dictionaries (same name but different color in every dictionary file):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="textBrush" Color="LightGreen" />
```

And then this is my datagrid definition:

```
<DataGrid Name="coilTabDG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" HeadersVisibility="Column" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="coilNumber" Width="100*" Foreground="{DynamicResource textBrush}" Binding="{Binding  Path='coilNum'}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thickness" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding  Path='thick'}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grade" Width="100*" Binding="{Binding  Path='grade'}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Could you guys help me how to make this column's foreground changing with changing of the color theme?
Any solution is appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a cell style referencing your resource

```
    <Style x:Key="CurrencyCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource textBrush}" />
    </Style>
```

Apply the style to your column definition

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="coilNumber" Width="100*" CellStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding  Path='coilNum'}"/>
```

Comment: So simple and elegant solution! It Works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad this helps :) Don't forget to mark the question as answered if everything's ok ;) Happy coding !